# tsc creates src folder in dist

Tags: typescript, typescript3.0

I have this folder structure:

```
- src
 - subdir1
 - subdir2
```

This is my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "strict": true,
    "types": [
      "mocha",
      "node"
    ]
  }
}
```

Calling `./node_modules/.bin/tsc` results in this folder structure:

```
- dist
  - src
   - subdir1
   - subdir2
- src
 - subdir1
 - subdir2
```

Why is `src` included in `dist`?

Comment: what if you add resolveJsonModule: true to tsconfig.json ?

Comment: My failure. I ignored another build error and thus the `dist` output has gone stale.

Answer (score 4):

I ran the same thing and in fact it is a building error.
In my case, i needed to get information of a file that was outside of 'src'.

Therefore, the TSC created the dir 'src' because my code "needed" to access something outside the folder 'src'.

Answer (score 0):

TSC will create `src` inside of `dist` if things outside of `src` are compiled as well as `src`. Since both the `src` and the other things are to be compiled into `dist`, it creates a `src` file inside of `dist` to distinguish it from the other things being compiled.

Assume you have some TypeScript like this:

```
MyProject/
    tsconfig.json
    src/
        myCode.ts
    someOtherFolder/
        otherCode.ts
    thirdTypeScriptFile.ts
```

Assume your outDir is named `dist`. If all you are doing is compiling `src`, then your compiled code will be:

```
MyProject/
    dist/
        myCode.js
```

Note that there is no `src` folder inside of `dist`. It doesn't make the `src` folder because it would be the only thing inside of `dist` if it did.

But suppose that your tsconfig.json is configured to also include `thirdTypeScriptFile.ts` and `someOtherFolder/otherCode.ts` in addition to compiling `src`. In that case you will end up with a `src` folder inside of your `dist` folder:

```
MyProject/
    dist/
        src/
            myCode.js
        someOtherFolder/
            otherCode.js
        thirdTypeScriptFile.js
```